# SQL Group by/ aggregate functions excluding records

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am trying to pull a comprehensive report of all transactions occuring in a month, from multiple different tables. The query I have built consistently excludes 96 transaction ids, all with the same account id. I cannot figure out why this is happening. Here is the code I have been using below. Any thoughts?

```
select activity_report_itemized.balance_transaction_id, 
max(activity_report_itemized.balance_transaction_created_at) AS "balance_transaction_created_at", 
max(activity_report_itemized.balance_transaction_reporting_category)AS "balance_transaction_reporting_category", 
max(activity_report_itemized.balance_transaction_component) AS "balance_transaction_component", 
max(activity_report_itemized.event_type) AS "event_type", 
max(activity_report_itemized.activity_at) AS "activity_at", 
max(activity_report_itemized.activity_interval_type) AS "activity_interval_type", 
max(activity_report_itemized.activity_start_time) AS "activity_start_time", 
max(activity_report_itemized.activity_end_time) AS "activity_end_time", 
max(activity_report_itemized.currency) AS "currency", 
max(activity_report_itemized.amount) AS "amount", 
max(activity_report_itemized.customer_facing_currency) AS "customer_facing_currency", 
max(activity_report_itemized.customer_facing_amount) AS "customer_facing_amount", 
max(activity_report_itemized.balance_transaction_description) AS "balance_transaction_description", 
max(activity_report_itemized.fee_id) AS "fee_id", 
max(activity_report_itemized.customer_id) AS "customer_id", 
max(activity_report_itemized.card_brand) AS "card_brand", 
max(activity_report_itemized.card_funding) AS "card_funding", 
max(activity_report_itemized.statement_descriptor) AS "statement_descriptor", 
max(activity_report_itemized.payment_method_type) AS "payment_method_type", 
max(activity_report_itemized.refund_id) AS "refund_id", 
max(activity_report_itemized.dispute_id) AS "dispute_id", 
max(activity_report_itemized.connected_account_id) AS "connected_account_id", 
max(activity_report_itemized.connected_account_name) AS "connected_account_name", 
max(connected_accounts_metadata.value) AS "Podium Org UID", 
max(payment_method_details.card_brand) AS "card_brand (including card present)", 
max(payment_method_details.card_funding) AS "card_funding (including card present)",
max(payment_method_details.card_network) AS "card_network", 
max(payment_method_details.type) AS "type",
max(case when payment_intents_metadata.key = 'podium_location_uid' then payment_intents_metadata.value end) AS "Podium Location UID",
max(case when payment_intents_metadata.key = 'payment_method_type' then payment_intents_metadata.value end) AS "Payment Method Type",
max(case when payment_intents_metadata.key = 'customer_name' then payment_intents_metadata.value end) AS "Customer Name",
max(case when payment_intents_metadata.key = 'sub_vertical' then payment_intents_metadata.value end) AS "Sub Vertical",
max(case when payment_intents_metadata.key = 'vertical' then payment_intents_metadata.value end) AS "Vertical"
from activity_report_itemized 
full join payment_intents_metadata using (payment_intent_id)
full join connected_accounts_metadata on activity_report_itemized.connected_account_id = connected_accounts_metadata.account
full join payment_method_details using (charge_id)
where activity_report_itemized.balance_transaction_created_at >= to_date('2022-05-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
and activity_report_itemized.balance_transaction_created_at <= to_date('2022-06-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
and connected_accounts_metadata.key = 'podium_organization_uid'
and activity_report_itemized.balance_transaction_reporting_category = 'charge'
and activity_report_itemized.balance_transaction_component = 'gross'
group by activity_report_itemized.balance_transaction_id
```

Comment: Note you `and connected_accounts_metadata.key = 'podium_organization_uid'` makes `full join connected_accounts_metadata ..` effectively inner as nulls are excluded. Not sure if it is to blame.

Comment: Is there another way to write that so it wouldn't exclude?